# Error "yum update" - Centos 7

Tags: centos7, yum, protected, versions

When I tried use "yum update" I get these message:

```
Error:  Multilib version problems found. This often means that the root
   cause is something else and multilib version checking is just
   pointing out that there is a problem. Eg.:

     1. You have an upgrade for libstdc++ which is missing some
        dependency that another package requires. Yum is trying to
        solve this by installing an older version of libstdc++ of the
        different architecture. If you exclude the bad architecture
        yum will tell you what the root cause is (which package
        requires what). You can try redoing the upgrade with
        --exclude libstdc++.otherarch ... this should give you an error
        message showing the root cause of the problem.

     2. You have multiple architectures of libstdc++ installed, but
        yum can only see an upgrade for one of those architectures.
        If you don't want/need both architectures anymore then you
        can remove the one with the missing update and everything
        will work.

     3. You have duplicate versions of libstdc++ installed already.
        You can use "yum check" to get yum show these errors.

   ...you can also use --setopt=protected_multilib=false to remove
   this checking, however this is almost never the correct thing to
   do as something else is very likely to go wrong (often causing
   much more problems).

   Protected multilib versions: libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686 != libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
   Error: Protected multilib versions: libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.i686 != libgcc-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
   Error: Protected multilib versions: glibc-2.17-196.el7_4.2.i686 != glibc-2.17-196.el7.x86_64
```

Before this happened I had executed yum update but it never ended and I killed the pid of a stuck yum update with this command:

```
kill -9 2514
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
rpm --erase --nodeps libstdc++
yum install libstdc++
```

You need not re-install libstdc++.

Source: https://ask.fedoraproject.org/en/question/37518/cant-install-some-packages-yum-fails-with-multilib-error/

[EDIT]

For `Error: ... Specifies Multiple Packages`:

```
rpm -qa | grep -iE "libstdc++"
```

Here you must get multiple entries of `libstdc++`, then do:

```
rpm -e --allmatches libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7 --nodeps
```

Do this recursively to resolve all the issues.

Source: https://ximunix.blogspot.in/2012/01/how-to-remove-packages-with-rpm-error.html

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

I get this:
rpm --erase --nodeps libstdc++

error: "libstdc++" specifies multiple packages:
libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.x86_64
  libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7.i686
  libstdc++-4.8.5-16.el7_4.1.x86_64

Comment: Thanks, I did that with the 3 errors and it was the solution.

Comment: Yeah, seems like `libstdc++`, `libgcc` and `glibc` seemed to have the problems. I would suggest you re-install them cleanly following some online guide as those packages are important.